# Names features importance plot after preprocessing

Tags: python, xgboost

Before building a model I make scaling like this

```
X = StandardScaler(with_mean = 0, with_std = 1).fit_transform(X)
```

and after build a features importance plot

```
xgb.plot_importance(bst, color='red')
plt.title('importance', fontsize = 20)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 10)
plt.ylabel('features', fontsize = 20)
```

[image]

The problem is that instead of feature's names we get f0, f1, f2, f3 etc.....
How to return feature's names?

thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

first we get list of feature names before preprocessing

```
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix( X, label=y)
dtrain.feature_names
```

Then

```
bst.get_fscore()
mapper = {'f{0}'.format(i): v for i, v in enumerate(dtrain.feature_names)}
mapped = {mapper[k]: v for k, v in bst.get_fscore().items()}
mapped
xgb.plot_importance(mapped, color='red')
```

that's all

Comment: I needed to use `bst.booster().get_score().items()` instead of 
 `bst.get_fscore().items()`, when the `bst` is instance of `XGBClassifier`.

Comment: I needed to use bst.get_booster().get_score().items()

Answer (score 1):

For xgboost 0.82, the answer is quite simple, just overwrite the feature names attribute with the list of feature name strings.

```
trained_xgbmodel.feature_names = feature_name_list
xgboost.plot_importance(trained_xgbmodel)
```

Comment: FYI, the previous answer didnt work for me with the latest version of xgboost.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the importance of Xgboost model (trained with `scikit-learn` like API) with:

```py
xgb.feature_importances_
```

To check what type of importance it is: `xgb.importance_type`. The importance type can be set in the Xgboost constructor. You can read about ways to compute feature importance in Xgboost in this [post](https://mljar.com/blog/feature-importance-xgboost/).