# Feature name after optimization

Tags: python, xgboost

This is related to [Names features importance plot after preprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38600813/names-features-importance-plot-after-preprocessing)

In my case the problem is in the graph:

```
for importance_type in ('weight', 'gain', 'cover'):
    print('%s:' % importance_type,bst.get_score(importance_type = importance_type))
    node_params = {'shape': 'box', #Green
                   'style' : 'filled, rounded',
                   'fillcolor': '#78fcb'}
xgb.to_graphviz(clf_xgb,size = '10,10',condition_node_params= node_params)
graph_data = xgb.to_graphviz(clf_xgb,size = '10,10',condition_node_params=node_params)
graph_data.view(filename= 'xgboost_response')
plt.show()
for importance_type in ('weight', 'gain', 'cover'):
    print('%s:' % importance_type,bst.get_score().items(importance_type = importance_type))
```

I add feature_names as an inside function , when I tried adding "feature_cols" manually ,which contains the feature names, I had an error. This code  doesn't show feature names

Any suggestion would be appreciated

*EDITED

```
    feature_cols = data_set_sub.columns[0:-1]
    X = data_set_sub[feature_cols] # Independent variables - features
    y = data_set_sub.New # Dependent variables - class
    y = y.to_list()
    le = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
    y = le.fit_transform(y)
    #* here goes the training/test split
```

Comment: Can you show where you're adding "feature_cols"?

Comment: Edited, I didn't show how I manually added it before, it didn't work so I guess it's irrelevant either

Answer (score 0):

Answer is in here:
[How do I include feature names in the plot_tree function from the XGBoost library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60186747/how-do-i-include-feature-names-in-the-plot-tree-function-from-the-xgboost-librar) by FChm

Several notes: first column starts with 0, second with your feature name and third with feature type: i.e: "q" / "i". Look out for duplicates! they can confuse your results

fmap added

```
xgb.to_graphviz(clf_xgb, size='10,10', condition_node_params=node_params,fmap='feature_map.txt')
            graph_data = xgb.to_graphviz(clf_xgb, size='10,10', condition_node_params=node_params,fmap='feature_map.txt')
            graph_data.view(filename='xgboost_response2')
            plt.show()
```